# Copying and Rearranging columns in excel with Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, formatting, copy-paste, openpyxl

I have data in an excel file, but for it to be useful I need to copy & paste the columns into a different order. 
I have figured out how to open & read my file and to write a new excel file. I can also get the data from the original, and paste it into my new file but not in a loop.

[here's an example of the data i'm working with to visualize my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odhxC.png) i need A1,B1,C1 next to each other and then A2,B2,C2, etc etc.

Here is my code from a smaller test file I created to play around with:

```
import openpyxl as op

wb = op.load_workbook('coding_test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

mylist = []
mylist2 = []
mylist3 = []


for row in ws.iter_rows('H13:H23'):
    for cell in row:
        mylist.append(cell.value)
for row in ws.iter_rows('L13:L23'):
    for cell in row:
        mylist2.append(cell.value)
for row in ws.iter_rows('P13:P23'):
    for cell in row:
        mylist3.append(cell.value)

print (mylist, mylist2, mylist3) 


new_wb = op.Workbook()
dest_filename = 'empty_coding_test.xlsx'
new_ws = new_wb.active

for row in zip (mylist, mylist2, mylist3):
    new_ws.append(row)

new_wb.save(filename=dest_filename)
```

I want to create a loop to do the rest of the work, but I can't figure out how to design it so that I don't have to code for each column and set.

Comment: do you want to move for example from H13:H23 TO I13:123?

Comment: @MauricioCortazar no, I would like to write the column H13:H23 as column A in the new file and then have L13:L23 be column B in the new file. I just want them to be arranged next to each other.

Comment: Use `zip` and `iter_rows()`

Answer (score 0):

well, you can recycle code doing something like:

```
import openpyxl as op

wb = op.load_workbook('coding_test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

new_wb = op.Workbook()
dest_filename = 'empty_coding_test.xlsx'
new_ws = new_wb.active

for row in ws.iter_rows('H13:H23'):
    for cell in row:
        new_ws['A%s' % cell].value = cell.value
for row in ws.iter_rows('L13:L23'):
    for cell in row:
        new_ws['B%s' % cell].value = cell.value
for row in ws.iter_rows('P13:P23'):
    for cell in row:
        new_ws['C%s' % cell].value = cell.value


new_wb.save(filename=dest_filename)
```

tell me if that work for you